# Login com Facebook - Não consigo logar no próprio aplicativo com a conta developer

Tags: api, facebook, login

Tenho um site, onde incluí login para usuários, usando o API do facebook.

Todos conseguem fazer o login normalmente, porém meu login de Administrador do aplicativo que criei para o login não entra, ou seja, único login que não funciona é o meu de administrador do aplicativo.

O seguinte erro é mostrado depois que clico no botão "Entrar":

> Invalid Scopes: publish_stream. This message is only shown to
>   developers. Users of your app will ignore these permissions if
>   present. Please read the documentation for valid permissions at:
>   https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions

Em meu código, eu não solicito essa permissão ao API, conforme segue:

```
function fb_login(){
    FB.login(function(response) { statusChangeCallback(response); }, {
        scope: 'publish_stream,email'
    });
}
```

Porque meu login é o único que não entra ?

Existe alguma liberação a ser feita dentro do aplicativo no facebook ?

**Obs**.: O aplicativo está com status "público".

> "Esse aplicativo é público e está disponível para todos os usuários"

Desde já agradeço qualquer ajuda que tiver

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A permissão `publish_stream` não existe mais. Se você precisa fazer publicações em nome do usuário, use `publish_actions`.
Apenas os desenvolvedores podem ver erros de permissão, é por isso que você é o único que não consegue fazer login. É como se o facebook estivesse dizendo: "ei, desenvolvedor, conserta isso!". No caso dos usuários, o erro é ignorado.

---

Se você não precisa publicar em nome do usuário, use:

```
function fb_login(){
    FB.login(function(response) { statusChangeCallback(response); }, {
        scope: 'email'
    });
}
```

Se precisa, use:

```
function fb_login(){
    FB.login(function(response) { statusChangeCallback(response); }, {
        scope: 'publish_actions,email'
    });
}
```

Comment: Alexandree, obrigado pela sua ajuda. Foi uma ajuda simples e bem explicada !!! Funcionou certinho, mais uma vez, obrigado !